# CentOS yum update: packages skipped because of dependency problems?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, software-updates

I'm in the process of updating a server running CentOS that hasn't been updated in years. There were over 400 packages to update, but 6 packages were skipped due to dependency problems. After updating all the other packages, I cleaned the yum cache and these 6 packages are still listed.

What does this mean and how do I resolve this? Will ignoring these skipped packages cause any problems for the system?

I should add that I'm doing this update as one of my first projects at my first IT job. A lot of this is new to me.

Comment: You can add a `-v` to `yum` to get more information. It should give you more info about why it can’t update them. You need to read them and figure it out.

Comment: This is very common for systems that haven't been updated in years. Do this: `yum clean all; rm -rf /var/cache/yum; yum makecache; yum -v update` and post the output of the last command in your question by editing it.

Comment: Impossible to answer given no output. I'm voting to close. Also no info given in terms of extra repos. Even CentOS version is not specified.